# MYSQL Sort Results By Nearest UTM Co-ordinates

Tags: php, mysql, location, coordinates, utm

I have a mysql table with location names with UTM co-ordinantes for each entry, i.e.

Name       X       Y
House 1    387000  406100 
House 2    394500  805300

I need a mysql query so that when a query where x and y co-ordinates are entered, it lists the results in order of nearest distance to the entry;

I am new so sorry if there is any vagueness. Answers much appreciated.

PHP Language please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to comments on your question

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217819/effectively-selecting-the-closest-distance-record-from-a-database) exactly answers your problem. And there is a link to a PHP example as well