# Find and order distance between locations in mysql with huge number of locations

Tags: mysql, node.js, geolocation

I have more than 500000 locations stored in MySQL database and will increase each day, and I need to retrieve the nearest 10 locations based on user's location.

I have managed to do this, but I'm facing a performance issue with these huge number of locations.

The query takes 7 sec to be executed.

I'm using query like this

```
select * from (select id,name ,calc_distance(long,lat) as distance from locatoin) as location_with_distance order by distance limit 10.
```

Based on above , what is the best practice to be used in these situations? Or if there is any database systems design to use in this situations?

**Note :- the main issue with the query is the ordering not calculating the distance function.**

Comment: No. The main issue IS calculating the distance function, not ordering it (mysql is pretty good at ordering stuff). Since you have to calculate all the distances first to be able to order them, your bottleneck here is your distance funtion. You can precalculate the distance to some default places (beacons) and use the beacons closest to your user to preselect the possible locations and only calculate the distance from those; or preselect by a square with delta lan < x and delta lat < x around your user. Or you might want to look into spatial index (and how to use it). Or a combination of these.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Effectively selecting the closest (distance) record from a database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217819/effectively-selecting-the-closest-distance-record-from-a-database)

Comment: @Solarflare, i tried to remove the order and performance was very good and acceptable. please note that calc_distance function doesn't do any io operations just math calculations.

Comment: @arhey thanks, i will check it and get back with the results

Comment: @Abdallah Al Barmawi, removing the `order by` but keeping the `limit 10` will tell mysql to just calculate the first 10 entries it finds. The `order by` forces mysql to calculate every distance first and then take the 10 closest ones. (But you want the 10 closest, so you need ordering). So the reason your query was fast before even with the distance function is `limit 10`, it made you skip 499.990 distance-calculations (remove `limit 10` with/without `order by` and you will see). So most optimization you can do is to try to similarly skip most of the 500.000 rows before distance calculation.

Comment: @Solarflare thanks, but changes my approach by adding more filters to the query such as the city of the location, and now i'm getting good performance. thanks all

Comment: @Abdallah Al Barmawi, yes, that is exactly what I meant, you preselect the rows before you calculate the distance function (here by city) - but keep in mind that for small cities or cities close to each other, you might have to include more than one city to get 10 locations. Good luck.